# In AS3, what's the deal with new <classname>() not causing the creationComplete event?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, mxml

I just now tracked down a bug in my code to the fact that the creationComplete event is not being raised by class Player.

Grid.mxml:

```
m_arrSpaces[4][4].entities.addItem(new Player());
```

Player.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Entity xmlns="entities.*" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="onCreationComplete">
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;

    private function onCreationComplete():void {
        Alert.show("cration");
        m_imgActiveImage = imgUp;
    }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

I know that the line in Grid.mxml is being run and that the Player object is being added to m_arrSpaces[4][4].entities.  I also know that Player.onCreationComplete() is never being called.  Wth?

EDIT: Wait, it's doing the same thing even when I correct the typo and include the parantheses in the MXML tag, as in:

```
creationComplete="onCreationComplete()"
```

EDIT: Oh, yeah, here's the code for Entity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Image;

        import spaces.Space;

        protected var m_imgActiveImage:Image;

        public function get activeImage():Image {
            return m_imgActiveImage;
        }

        private function onCreationComplete():void {
            width = Space.SPAN - 4;
            height = width;
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have this:
creationComplete="onCreationComplete"

and it should be:

creationComplete="onCreationComplete()"

did a quick test on new application with and alert and never reached the onComplete() method.

Comment: Sorry, stupid oversight.  I'm voting to close the post.  Thanks!

Comment: Wait, it's still not getting called?

Comment: i meant that, without the parentheses in component tags, u never reach the method, unlike adding event listeners, where u only need the method name.

Also, seems that the complete event only gets dispatched when the components is fully created (like addChild/addElement to aruning component), for instantiation u have to use preinitialize event.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, looks like another problem at hand was that

```
m_arrSpaces[4][4].addChild(new Player());
```

was needing to be called to get everything to work, not

```
m_arrSpaces[4][4].entities.addItem(new Player());
```